# Pardot form - comment field not showing value for existing leads

Tags: form, pardot

I have added a 'comments' field in a pardot form. This field by default maps to 'pardot comments' in SF. If someone fills the form and gives comment, this value is shown in 'pardot comment' field in SF, however if the visitor filling the form is already there in our record, his 'comment' field value is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Pardot by default will not show fields in a form when they have already been filled out.

When editing form fields there is the option checkbox on the "Advanced" tab to select "Always display even if previously completed"

Use for fields for which the prospect can submit the same value more than once. If this option isn’t enabled, the field doesn’t display again after a prospect has completed it.

This is referenced from:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_forms_field_options.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Hi Richard, I think I didn't explained it well. Problem in not in showing the fields in form as the fields are always showing up and visitor is able to fill them up. However, if a record already exist in pardot and salesforce and that record gets updated via form, those values are not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your custom field mapping in Pardot. You likely have a Sync Behavior value of "Use Salesforce's Value". With this value, Pardot changes are overwritten to be whatever is last found in Salesforce.

Consider changing this value to either of the following 2 options, depending on how you update the field and what should stick:

- Use Pardot' Value (only use if this field is **only** updated from Pardot
- Use the most recently updated record (Pardot will pick the value from the record most recently updated, allowing both Salesforce and Pardot to update the value)